# Android Firebase storage retry download when it fails

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase Storage to allow users of my app to upload/download files.
I've checked the docs for the possible errors and I've noticed the method [`StorageException#getIsRecoverableException()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageException.html#getIsRecoverableException()).

For some operations, like loading user picture, I would like to retry the download programmatically (if the error is recoverable) and also I would like to handle the number of attempts (i.e. the download should be tried for max 3 times, if it fails all the times I would give up and I will display an error message to the user).

[`StorageReference#getFile(File)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getFile(java.io.File)) returns a [`FileDownloadTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask), but I can't see any method in this class which does what I want.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried? I don't think there is a method that can do that auto for you. You can catch the exception and retrieve retry running the download method if existing chucks of data exist. if not, download from beggining.